# How to user Affter(:build) rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have enum include the following:

`enum dv_type: { only_rental: 0, rental_buy: 1, only_one: 2 }`

after I have validates enum if it is 1 and 2 then the `price` will be > 0, and ` will be equal to 0

`fatories/items.rb`

`price: 25000`

`dv_type { Item.dv_types.except(:only_one).keys.sample }`

Now I want to use affter (: build) to set value by type, what should I do?

type = 0 then price = 0

type = 1 and 2 then price > 0

Comment: Can you explain further what you're trying to do? I'm having problems understanding this "_after I have validates enum if it is 1 and 2 then the price will be > 0, and will be equal to 0_".

Comment: While creating the item I want when the type is only_rental, the price will be = 0, while the type is rental_by, only_one the price will be greater than zero.

Comment: You want to set the value of a column X depending on the value of a column Y, is that right? How are you going to set a price greater than zero?

Comment: What I understood is, in your factory you want to set price based on the type set, right? Also I don't understand why you randomly set the type. It will make your tests flaky. You should use traits instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Factories should usually not contain random data. Your test suite will be more stable if you just always return one of the values for dv_type and use traits to choose the others.

However, what you're asking is easily doable. You can reference other columns in your factory.

```
dv_type { Item.dv_types.except(:only_one).keys.sample }
price { dv_type.zero? ? 0 : 25000 }
```